# Java получение дат прошлой недели

Tags: java, алгоритм, дата, calendar

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в java правильно и просто получить список будних дней между датами?
С например, на вход в метод кидаем Date(12.11.2018), Date(20.11.2018)

И он возвращает ArrayList(12.11.2018, 13.11.2018, 14.11.2018, 15.11.2018, 16.11.2018, 19.11.2018)

Как мне кажется, можно это сделать с помощью class Calendar, однако из за разности в  формировании календарей( там неделя начинается с воскресенья)
Возникает большая путаница и не удается ничего адекватного получить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте `LocalDate`

```
    LocalDate localDate1  = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 5);
    LocalDate localDate2  = LocalDate.of(2018, 11, 25);
    List <LocalDate> dates = new ArrayList<>();

    // добавляем в список все дни от начального до конечного
    // если день недели не больше 5 (пятница)
    for (LocalDate date = localDate1 ; !date.isAfter(localDate2); date = date.plusDays(1)){
        if (date.getDayOfWeek().getValue() > 5) continue;
        dates.add(date);
    }

    // проверяем 
    for (LocalDate date : dates) {
        System.out.println(date + "  " + date.getDayOfWeek());
    }
```

Comment: Условие более читабельно без `continue`

Comment: К `continue` или `break`надо только привыкнуть. Если таких условий два, пять, пятнадцать... объединение их в единую конструкцию `if else if if else if...` становиться нечитабельным. Запись же `одно условие - одно действие` прекрасно и читается и редактируется.

Comment: В данном случае как раз и будет одно условие, без `else`

Comment: Супер, это именно то, что нужно!

Спасибо)

Пользуясь случаем, задам еще вопрос по LocalDate.

Я могу взять первую дату месяца вот так -
YearMonth month = YearMonth.now();
LocalDate start = month.atDay(1);

Как я могу взять дату предыдущего понедельника и пятницы?